# Is it good design to create an object inside a getter?

Tags: oop

I have a bean class, say, **Teacher** that has a status *active* or *inactive* and each of those states have an identifier. To implement this behaviour, my team decided to have a Status bean with both the *id* and *name* attributes.

Now, let's say I'm a client of a service that uses a **Teacher** bean. In order to use said service I would have to create the **Teacher** bean:

```
Teacher teacher = new Teacher();
teacher.setName("Some name");
...
Status status = new Status();
status.setId(1);
...
teacher.setStatus(status);
```

The question is: would It be good OOP design if we implement the *Teacher.getStatus()* as

```
Status status = null;

Status getStatus() {
    if (status != null) {
        return status;
    } else {
        return new Status();
    }
}
```

So I don't call the **Status** constructor anytime I want to create a **Teacher** bean. Like this:

```
Teacher teacher = new Teacher();
teacher.setName("Some name");
teacher.getStatus().setId(1);
```

Would that be considered a bad practice? If so, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not bad practice, per se, but it seems unnecessary in this example. If the object you're writing a getter for has a lot of overhead on construction - if it's being pulled out of a database, for example - this general approach is quite reasonable. There is, however, one thing you'll want to fix. Instead of creating and returning a new Status object, set `this.status=new Status()` and return it. That way you won't create two new Status objects if you call `getStatus()` twice.

Comment: You might also want to synchronize the getter.  So that the item only gets created once, even if multiple thread access the getter.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a bad design to return a new in a function. It will bring you to memory leaks. Each time you'll call getStatus you will create a new Status without deleting it. You can easily have the same design like this:

```
Teacher teacher = new Teacher();
teacher.setName("some name");
teacher.getStatus().setId(1);

public class Teacher{
    private Status myStatus = new Status();
    public void Teacher(){...}
    public Status getStatus(){return myStatus;}
}

public class Status{
    private int Id = 0;
    public void Status(){...}
    public void setId(int p_id){Id = p_id}
}
```

Comment: Point well taken. Now, regarding the code you just gave me. Would that be considered a bad practice?

Comment: I think this would be a good pratice. But overflow community should validate my answer.